# Rename files in Score Order using Bash

Tags: bash, file, sorting

I'm a professional musician and frequently need to rename lists of 20-30 .PDF files so that they sort in score order. For instance, I have a list of files such as:

```
Rolling Thunder Eb Clarinet  - 4p.PDF
Rolling Thunder Flute 1 - 4p
Rolling Thunder Flute 2 - 4p
Rolling Thunder FULL SCORE - CONDENSED - 20p
Rolling Thunder Horn in F 1 - 3p
Rolling Thunder EDIT 9-7-15 Horn in F 2 - 3p
...
```

and I need them renamed so they sort (in the Finder) in the order they appear in a score, viz:

```
00 - Rolling Thunder FULL SCORE - CONDENSED - 20p
01 - Rolling Thunder Flute 1 - 4p
02 - Rolling Thunder Flute 2 - 4p
... etc.
```

I have gone about this by creating a text file (so that the order can be modified as needed for various contexts) containing the order of instruments, such as:

```
Piccolo
Flute
Oboe
Clarinet
Bassoon
French Horn
...
```

and then started a Bash script to find files in this order:

```
while read line; do 
find . -name "*$line*" 
done < scoreorder.txt
```

I'm not sure how to build on this to rename the files in a sequence. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is "score order"?

Comment: @erip I think the `scoreorder.txt` defines that, albeit incompletely.

Comment: Do you have both `Horn` and `French Horn`?  Are there other entries which are substrings of each other?

Comment: @erip Score order is the order instruments are (historically/traditionally) listed in a music score, though this is subject to a lot of contextual factors, so I need to set it up so that the order can be specified via a text file.

Comment: @triplee  - Theoretically yes, but in practice it would be fine to have as a stipulation that each instrument has its own unique identifier that is not a substring of another.

Comment: My answer could be simplified a bit then but it's probably not a very important optimization.

Comment: I have no idea why this was marked off-topic.  This is a valid question about programming in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no unrelated files in the directory, perhaps something like this.

To get a listing of all PDF files, just `printf` a matching glob.

```
printf '%s\n' *.pdf
```

Let's pipe that to an Awk script which maps these to an index number from `scoreorder.txt`.  First, read the file into an array `a` with a numeric index for each entry we read.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[++n] = $0; next } ...' scoreorder.txt -
```

The `NR==FNR` will be true when we read `scoreorder.txt`; the rest of the script will be applied to lines we read from standard input, from the `printf` above.

```
... { m=0;
    for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        if ($0 ~ a[i])
            if (m==0 || length(a[m]) < length(a[i])) m=i;
```

On each line, we pick out the index from the longest match (so `French Horn` takes precedence over `Horn` regardless of where they are in the index).  If there is no match, `m` will be 0.

```
    printf("%i\t%s\n", m, $0); }'
```

This will produce a "raw sort" where the `FULL SCORE` will have prefix 00 (because it did not match any keyword) and e.g. the `Flute` files will have prefix 02.  This is enough to sort the list.

```
| sort -n |
```

Now we just need to number the lines and post-process slightly to remove the "raw sort" numbers.

```
awk -F '\t' '{ printf "mv \"%s\" \"%02i - %s\"\n", $2, NR, $2 }'
```

The sort order at this point is still slightly off -- the `EDIT` in the second `Horn` file name blows the sort order.  Maybe you simply want to fix your naming convention, or perhaps you want to pick up the final number before `.pdf` as a secondary sort key.

The output is a piece of shell script which you can pipe to `sh` once you are satisfied that it does what it's supposed to do.  Here's still the final script.

```
printf '%s\n' *.pdf |
awk 'NR==FNR { a[++n] = $0; next }
    { m=0;
        for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
            if ($0 ~ a[i])
                if (m==0 || length(a[m]) < length(a[i])) m=i;
    printf("%i\t%s\n", m, $0); }' scoreorder.txt - |
sort -n |
awk -F '\t' '{ printf "mv \"%s\" \"%02i - %s\"\n", $2, NR, $2 }'
```

If you have file names which contain double quotes, tabs, or newlines, this is going to get a lot more tricky.  I simply assumed you don't.

Comment: This is so extremely helpful, and so much further than I got in days of trying this task (I'm pretty new at this) Thank you! However, I neglected to mention there are usually multiple parts within each instrument group, so that the files will end up being named things like " .... Flute 1", " ... Flute 2", and so on, before going on to the next instrument, and potentially in numbers that will differ from one instrument/score to the next. Any suggestions for handling this, other than putting these individually into scoreorder.txt? In the meantime I'm going to study the code you supplied me.